# Chrome Extensions that modify pages suddenly makes that page not load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

All of a sudden, all Chrome extensions that modify pages started acting weird.

I first noticed this when I tried to go on Google but it wouldn't load, then I tried to go on Facebook which wouldn't load either. Then I tried clicking on a bunch of my bookmarks only to realize that none of them were working.

Then I booted up Firefox and Google loaded perfectly along with all the other sites I had tried.

Then I went to chrome://extensions and disabled *all* extensions. Now everything loaded just fine in Chrome.

So I started experimenting, I wanted to find the bad extension. Unfortunately there seemed to be multiple.

I enabled all extensions that didn't seem to cause trouble and then experimented.

My conclusion seems to be this:

- All sites that are modified by an extension, will not load.

Let me give you an example:

*Adblock* modifies all webpages, so naturally nothing loaded because of that.
*Facebook Full-size Profile Pictures* modifies **.facebook.com* which resulted in Facebook not loading.

I tried installing a bunch of different extensions and the result always seemed to be the same: Whenever I used an extension that modified a site, it would not load on that site.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Note that it just suddenly stopped working, and that I was not messing with any settings, at least not deliberately. Could a Chrome update have caused it?

**EDIT I:** I only just realized that after being on YouTube for ~5 seconds, the tab freezes and I have to close it to access YouTube again.

**EDIT II:** Actually it seems to be when the page has loaded completely it freezes. Only happens for YouTube though so it seems to be a more localized problem. I disabled the extension *Page Ruler* and it seemed to fix it. I am unsure why it was causing this issue.

**EDIT III:** Stuff is getting even weirder. YouTube kept on freezing so I disabled *all* extensions but it's still freezing; even in incognito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. It seemed to be a virus on my system that Avast didn't detect.

It was a process call *FontEditor.exe* that Task Manager, cmd and process explorer refused to kill.

I booted my PC into safe mode and deleted the executable which solved the issue.